# Optimization problem - minimizing a function in R

Tags: r, optimization, minimization

I want to minimize a function but can not get ahead.

Problem setting:

```
mtcars$gender <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 4), rep(1, 6), rep(0 , 12))

predictions <- data.frame(
  c(0.05,   0.03,   0.99,   0.07,   0.00,   0.10,   0.00,   0.84,   0.92,   0.01,   0.03,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   1.00,   1.00,   1.00,   0.97,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   1.00,   0.86,   0.84,   0.01,   0.08,   0.00,   0.86),
  c(0.95,   0.97,   0.01,   0.80,   0.07,   0.82,   0.00,   0.14,   0.08,   0.95,   0.94,   0.03,   0.03,   0.03,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.03,   0.02,   0.07,   0.02,   0.01,   0.00,   0.12,   0.16,   0.10,   0.79,   0.05,   0.13),
  c(0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.13,   0.93,   0.08,   1.00,   0.02,   0.00,   0.04,   0.03,   0.97,   0.97,   0.97,   1.00,   1.00,   1.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.98,   0.93,   0.98,   0.99,   0.00,   0.02,   0.00,   0.89,   0.13,   0.95,   0.01))
colnames(predictions) <- c(4, 6, 8)


actual.probs <- apply(predictions, 1, which.max) 
actual.probs <- as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(table(mtcars$gender, actual.probs)))
real.probs <- data.frame(matrix(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3))
```

I used a prediction algorithm which gives me probabilites to a car to have 4,6 or 8 cyl. The result is stored in "predictions". However the distribution (`actual.probs`) differs from the distribution seen in reality (`real.probs`). To adjust that, i want to multiply the probalities by a weight, get the one with the highest probability and recalculate the table. The result I want is the weights i need to get the smallest deviation from the real distribution.

```
optimresult <- predictions 

fn <- function(v) {
  weight1 <- v[1]
  weight2 <- v[2]
  weight3 <- v[3]

  optimresult[,1] <- optimresult[,1] * weight1
  optimresult[,2] <- optimresult[,2] * weight2
  optimresult[,3] <- optimresult[,3] * weight3

  result <- apply(optimresult, 1, which.max) # get highest probablity

  actualprobs <- prop.table(table(mtcars[["gender"]], result))
  return <- sum(abs(real.probs - actualprobs))
}

optim(c(1, 1, 1), fn)
```

Startvalues are all one, however the function seems not to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so, you want to multiply the actual probs by a constant such that the new matrix values come as close as possible from the real probs, is this correct? Is it one constant that you want to multiply by or 6 constants (one per number)? I mean, to get the constant per number is as simple as dividing each number in real probabilities by actual probs, the division from that matrix will get you 6 constants. But I might be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: yes, it is correct, i want to new matrix values as close as possible to the real probs. I expect that to happen by using different numbers or weight1, weight2 and weight3, since they change the original value of the probability. I already tried a bruce force approach with random numbers, but this is quite computationally expensive

Comment: Another observation: In this step of your function "result <- apply(optimresult, 1, which.max) " you are not pulling the highest probability, you are pulling the index or position of your highest probability

Comment: what happens if you divide actual.probs/real.probs ? Aren't those numbers the constant to make the matrices equal? (I mean, under R standard of matrix multiplication)

Comment: yes but the index of the highest probability gives me the actual class the algorithm would predict. I need it to build the table. The probablities just help me to get there and they are the values i have to manipulate

Comment: yes that is the case, this gives me 6 values in my case. But how do I use to get these values back weights for my predicted probablities?

Comment: Ok, for example you want to turn 0.15625 (top left in actual probs) to 0.1(real.probs), then you simply multiply by 0.64.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but this step is not the last one. What i need is three numbers (the weights) to multiply with each column of my predictions :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Jorge, Adam Waring provided a great answer, which solves my issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that small changes to the parameter values in optim() do not change the result meaning that the algorithm thinks it has converged before it actually has.

Using method SANN gives a better result. I am not sure whether it is the best result you can get with that sample dataset.

I also made some simplifications to your function.

```
fn <- function(v) {

  weighted_preds = predictions * v

  result = apply(weighted_preds, 1, which.max) # get highest probablity

  actualprobs = prop.table(table(mtcars[["gender"]], result))

  sum(abs(real.probs - actualprobs))
}

optim(c(100, 1, 1), fn, method="SANN")
```

Try different starting values to see if you can get an improvement. Increasing the number of predictions will also help.

Comment: This function is locally constant which makes it difficult for `optim` to go ahead. Never use method "SANN", it is one of the most problematic optimization procedures available in R. If you need to apply a global optimizer, think of packages *DEoptim* or *GenSA*. For your function, I find a minimum of 0.0875 in a reasonably wide domain. Also consider using `(fit-data)^2` instead of `abs(fit-data)` as being a smoother objective function.